# PATINDEX and SUBSTRING not returning correct values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have the following query:

```
select [Service Item Value],
  SUBSTRING
  (
    [Service Item Value],
    PATINDEX('%[3][C][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', 
      [Service Item Value]),
    10
  ) AS [Circuit Reference]
FROM [dbo].[3c_and_2c_Report_Multiple_customers];
```

The query should look for any string in the service item value column and extract just any string that is 10 characters in length and starts with 3C. It is doing that (see the last results of the query) but, when there is no pattern match it just returns whatever it wants

```
Service Item Value                     Circuit Reference
38159 (Cease) & 38160 (Re-Provide)          38159 (Ce
384K                                        384K
3925 bundle no. 1230                        3925 bund
3C00156746                                  3C00156746
P752480A,C72/217777*3C00190634,             3C00190634
P0638887A, C72/23872 * 3C00193454           3C00193454
(C72/29814 * P0647973A)>3C00231114 *        3C00231114`
```

Basically if there is no pattern match then leave the `Circuit Reference` column blank.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`PATINDEX` will return 0 if there is no match, or 1 if there is a match on the first character...(2 for second char, etc)

`SUBSTRING` will accept 0 as the second *start* parameter.

So you are basically allowing a failed `PATINDEX` to still return a sub string.

Perhaps use a `CASE` expression to trap the zero return from `PATINDEX`

```
CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%[3][C][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', [Service Item Value]) = 0 THEN ''
ELSE
SUBSTRING([Service Item Value],PATINDEX('%[3][C][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', [Service Item Value]),10) 
END AS [Circuit Reference]
```

Comment: This is the right answer. (but it's a `CASE` *expression*)

Comment: You can also do this without repeating the patindex expression. `SUBSTRING([Service Item Value], 
  COALESCE(NULLIF(PATINDEX('%[3][C][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', [Service Item Value]), 0), LEN([Service Item Value])+1), 10)`

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps another option

**Example**

```
Select *
      ,[Circuit Reference]=substring([Service Item Value],patindex('%3C[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%',[Service Item Value]+'3C0000000000'),10)
 From  YourTable
```

**Returns**

```
Service Item Value                     Circuit Reference
38159 (Cease) & 38160 (Re-Provide)  
3845 cisco router   
384K    
384K    
3925 bundle no. 1230    
3925 router; bundle :1230   
3C00156746                              3C00156746
P752480A,C72/217777*3C00190634,         3C00190634
P0638887A, C72/23872 * 3C00193454       3C00193454
(C72/29814 * P0647973A)>3C00231114 *    3C00231114
```

Comment: Clever :) Neat way to overcome what becomes a messy expression

Comment: @Grantly Very kind  :)

Answer (score 1):

It's not returning "Whatever" it wants, it's returned exactly what you've told it to.

If `PATINDEX` doesn't find the pattern it is looking for, it'll return the value 0. This means, effectively, your expression becomes `SUBSTRING([Service Item Value],0,10)`, so you get the 10 most left characters.

If you don't want a value to returned, use a CASE:

```
SELECT [Service Item Value],
       CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%[3][C][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', [Service Item Value]) > 0 THEN SUBSTRING([Service Item Value],PATINDEX('%[3][C][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', [Service Item Value]),10) END AS [Circuit Reference],
FROM [dbo].[3c_and_2c_Report_Multiple_customers];
```